# Git apply patch fails silently (no errors but nothing happens)

Tags: git, patch, msysgit

I'm trying to apply a patch, and git apply patch doesn't give me any errors:

```
sashoalm@SASHOALM-PC /c/Workspace/tesseract-git/api (master)
$ git apply ../../commit-d0d9477

sashoalm@SASHOALM-PC /c/Workspace/tesseract-git/api (master)
$
```

As you can see, no error messages are given. But when I open the history, nothing is committed, and the index is empty. It's as if I haven't issued the `git apply` command.

I'm at a loss how to troubleshoot this, since there no errors to Google.

**Edit:** I forgot to say, but I'm trying to transplant my patches from a repository of Tesseract, where I got the source without version control, created my own empty git repo, and made some commits. Later I cloned the Tesseract repository using `git svn`, and now I'm trying to move my patches there.

Comment: Maybe the changes, the patch tries to apply, are already in your repository? In that case the patch would apply but nothing would change. At least that's what I think it does.

Comment: @Zeeker Not in my case - those changes were made by me, there's no way they would be in the official repo I cloned.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I found this while googling for the issue: http://data.agaric.com/git-apply-does-not-work-from-within-local-checkout-unrelated-git-repository

> `git apply` will fail to do anything when used within a local checkout of a git repository (other than the one for the project the patch is made for), such as if you are patching a module that is within a site that is in Git version control.
>
> Use `patch -p1 < path/file.patch` instead.

Comment: I was pulling my hair out trying to understand why git returns success (status 0) but does not apply patches when I try to run it from a subdirectory. Now I know that I have to always make sure that `git apply` is run from the root of my repository. This might be tricky in automated scripts.

Comment: Thanks. I was applying git patch from a subdirectory and it was failing silently. Just had to go to root and apply patch and it was happy.

Comment: Thanks, was equally irritated that i can't trust git apply now !

Comment: Thanks, @JustAMartin, you saved my bacon (and sanity).

Comment: For me the solution was to call `git apply` in the root directory of the git repository (it was a diff from one commit to another of that same repo and I didn't call `git diff` in the repos root dir)

Answer (score 2):

Further to B_'s answer, you might think that using `git diff --no-prefix` would mean you don't need to use the -p flag on `patch`. It appears you would be wrong, at least in the versin of `patch` I have here (2.5), no -p flag is not the same as -p0. -p0 works.

Answer (score 1):

Run `git apply` with `-v` option to see more information from git.

> ```
>    -v, --verbose
>        Report progress to stderr. By default, only a message about the current patch being applied will be printed. This option will cause additional information to be reported.
> ```

In my case the patch was silently skipped because of wrong directory from where `git apply` was run.